# MySQL query returning 0 when the real value is not 0

Tags: mysql, sql

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `field` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `value` text COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci;

INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `field`, `value`) VALUES
(1, 'first_name', '0'),
(2, 'last_name', '0'),
(3, 'first_name', '1'),
(4, 'last_name', '1');
```

Query:

```
SELECT MAX(`id`), `field`, `value` FROM test_table GROUP BY `field`
```

To my understand this should return the value of each fields with the higher id.

But it's returning:

```
MAX(`id`)    field          value
3            first_name     0
4            last_name      0
```

It's returning the correct id, the correct fields but the wrong values. What's going on here and how can I fix it to return rows 3 and 4?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. Will return a random value.

Comment: How can I get the value with the highest id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.`id`, t.`field`, t.`value` 
FROM test_table t
JOIN (SELECT MAX(`id`) AS `id`, `field` 
      FROM test_table 
      GROUP BY `field`) t1 ON t1.`id` = t.`id`
```